# How do I open a link in the system browser from content in an in app browser in cordova?

Tags: cordova

I've seen plenty of examples of how to do this from content in the main html/js code of the cordova app,

for example:

```
window.open(url, "_system");
```

but it doesn't seem to work when the link is in the content already in an in app browser.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: inAppBrowser doesn't allow that, you'll need to create your own plugin

Answer (score 2):

That is not quite enough, I think you are missing step 1 below. Here are the steps I am using to get this to work well:

1. Make sure you have an access tag for the external site in your `config.xml` as follows (obviously replacing `*google*` with whatever matched your site).

   `<access origin="*google.*" launch-external="yes" />`
2. Add a class to all the links you want to work this way. I use the `external` class name
3. Add the following delegated event handler to your document (this example uses jQuery)

   `jQuery(document).delegate('.external', 'click', function (e) {
       window.open(e.target.href, '_system');
       e.preventDefault();
   });`

The `e.preventDefault()` is important to ensure the browser does not try to handle the click itself

Now it should work