# InAppBrowser plugin for Cordova/Phonegap -- window.open not opening links in default browser

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm trying to add the InApBrowser PhoneGap plugin to my web app in order to open the links in the mobile default browser.

The webapp is programmed with AngularJS and IonicFramework.

I know there are very similar questions, but none of the solutions I've tried has worked so far.

So when I create the *apk file* and run it on my Android phone device some things don't work as expected. By the way, I build the *apk file* through the https://build.phonegap.com/.

In my [index](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/smartculm_test/blob/master/www/index.html) file I have this function:

```
    <!-- JQuery library -->
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.external', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open(e.target.href, '_system');
        });
    </script>
```

One of my problems is that with [this piece of code](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/smartculm_test/blob/master/www/templates/noticia.html):

```
  <p>
    <a id="btn-noticias" class="button button-block button-stable external" 
        ng-href="{{noticia.uri}}">
      Ver noticia en la web
    </a>
  </p>
```

the link is opened in the appview, not in the default browser.

And in [this piece of code](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/smartculm_test/blob/master/www/templates/examenesSeptiembre.html):

```
            <a class="item lista-item examen external" ng-repeat="examen in filteredExSept"
               ng-href="{{examen.URI}}"
               ng-hide="errorConexionExSept || examenesSeptiembre.length==0 || filteredExSept.length==0">
                <div class="tituloExamen" ng-bind-html="examen.asignatura"></div>
            </a>
```

the app doesn't even open the link, not in the browser, no in the appview...just doesn't open the link.

Here you can see may [config.xml](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/smartculm_test/blob/master/config.xml) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.myapp377389" 
        version="0.0.1" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <name>SmartCULM</name>

    <description>
        An application...
    </description>

    <author email="gps_e25@googlegroups.com">
      Daniel García Páez
    </author>

    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>

    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

     <!-- Core plugins -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="img/apk_icon.png" />
</widget>
```

**So, anyone knows if I'm doing something wrong? Either with the InAppBrowser plugin or with the angularjs code?**

You can access to my whole project [here](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/smartculm_test).

**UPDATE**
I've found the next information in the [PhoneGap documentation](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/03/20/access-tags/) for the access tag (also known as whitelist) in the config.xml:

> on Android, if a domain is whitelisted, a link will take over the entire webview. If it is not, it will open in the browser.

So, as I understand it, if I want to open in the default browser all my links (http://culm.unizar.es/* & https://culm.unizar.es/*) I have to avoid including them in the whitelist. **¿How I do that? I'm a little confused...I've tried but not sure if doing it ok.**

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @NicRaboy As I said, in the first piece of code I've posted the app open the link inside the app, not in the default browser. And in the second piece of code, the app doesn't even open the link at all.

Comment: looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801070/how-do-i-open-a-link-in-the-system-browser-from-content-in-an-in-app-browser-in/27803285#27803285

Comment: @unobf I've tried that solution and it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @unobf I've updated my question with recent research...if helps anyway...

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use, as compiled from several sources here:

```
    var externalLinkToOpen = $(this).attr("href");
    if (app.isPhoneGap()) {
        if (device.platform === 'Android') {
            navigator.app.loadUrl(externalLinkToOpen, { openExternal: true });
        } else {
            window.open(externalLinkToOpen, '_system');
        }
    } else {
        window.open(externalLinkToOpen, "_blank");
    }
```

The "app.isPhoneGap" just checks if device == undefined to see if running as website (almost all my apps I build as a website).  And, yes, I have the InApp browser plugin in the project also.

Comment: still not working for me. I've tried so many alternatives...I'm pretty sure it must be some related with a wrong configuration of the InAppBrowser plugin in my project. I'm positive I've added it with the "cordova plugin add" command and it's also added in the "config.xml". It is possible to give me an example of one of your projects configuration? When you say that "And yes, I have the InApp browser plugin in the project also", how exactly did you do it? Maybe I'm missing something in the way...

Comment: By the way, in the "app.isPhoneGap" sentence, "app" and "isPhoneGap", are global variables from the InAppBrowsre or what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, app is namespace object for a list of common functions that I use.  isPhoneGap() is one of the functions:
`App.prototype.isPhoneGap = function () {
  return !(device == undefined);
};`

Comment: I supposed something like that. But...nothing yet, still opening the links in the appview instead of the default browser. That's why I suspect it must be something related with wrong configuration of the InAppBrowser plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Please update if it worked< I have the same issue with android