# PhoneGap <access/> tag for InAppBrowser plugin whitelist not working. Links don't opening in default browser

Tags: android, cordova, browser, whitelist

In the [PhoneGap documentation](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/03/20/access-tags/) (after hours of research and try&error tests with my code) I've found this information:

> on Android, if a domain is whitelisted, a link will take over the entire webview. If it is not, it will open in the browser.

So, as I understand it, if I want all my external links my app access

- http://culm.unizar.es
- htpps://culm.unizar.es

to be opened with the default browser I would have to avoid including them in the whitelist.

I've tried with several cases in my *[config.xml](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/smartculm_test/blob/master/config.xml)*:

```
<access origin="http://*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="https://*" launch-external="yes" />

<access origin="*culm.unizar.es*" launch-external="yes" />

<access origin="*" launch-external="yes" />

Not access tag at all.
```

And it seems that my app always open the links in the appview instead of the browser.

You can access [the whole project here](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/smartculm_test) and more related information in [another StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001088/inappbrowser-plugin-for-cordova-phonegap-window-open-not-working-properly) question of mine.

Comment: No @delkant, sadly I didn't. I let my app with this little bug...